# TPM/TSS Linux API alternatives

Tags: linux, security, api, cryptography, tpm

I would like to find (mature) **API alternatives** to use TPM (**Trusted Platform Module**) funcionality on Linux (and maybe other *nix). I'm interested in trusted encrypt/decrypt functions for authentication (probably integrating with Kerberos).

I found **jTSS** (for Java) and **[TrouSerS](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/)**, but I would like to know about other alternatives, if any. "Googling" was not so useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there are not so many alternatives.

Currently there is an JSR in progress to establish an High Level Java API for trusted computing: http://jsr321.dev.java.net/

You can also use libtpm and the tpm_utils which are based on [IBM's TPM lib](http://ibmswtpm.sourceforge.net/).

btw for the archives: jTSS can be found at http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/